# Odd strtok behavior

Tags: c, strtok

I've been trying to use strtok in order to write a polynomial differentiation program, but it seems to be behaving oddly. At this point I've told it to stop at the characters ' ', [, ], (, and ). But for some reason, when passed input such as "Hello[]" it returns "Hello\n"

Is there anything wrong with my code here? All the polynomial string is is the text "Hello[]"

```
void differentiate(char* polynomial) 
{
    char current[10];
    char output[100];

    strncpy(current, strtok(polynomial, " []()/\n"), 10);
    printf("%s", current);

} // differentiate()
```

EDIT : It appears to be an issue related to the shell, and it would also appear to not be a newline after all, as when I use bash it does not occur, but when I use fish, I get the following:

[image]

I've never seen this kind of thing before, does anyone have any advice? Is this just a quirk of fish?

Comment: How do you know it's appending a newline character at the end of the token?

Comment: Beware of newline translation.  Depending on your OS, you may need to specify `\r` as well.

Comment: It's the carriage return character. Windows machines typically implement newlines as `\r\n` while Unices (including Mac OS X) just use `\n`.

Comment: All of this is being done on an OS X machine, so would that still be a problem? And adding \r to the delimiters did not solve the problem, either.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around your %s to where the newline is being inserted. eg printf("'%s'", current);

Comment: @AlexP You could check the last character by typing `youprogram | hexdump` and see the hexdump of your output.

Comment: Yup, it's not actually in the string, looks like it's something weird going on with the shell. Anyone familiar with it? Added an image into the OP.

Comment: The little `⏎` is fish's way of saying "I'm adding a newline because otherwise the shell would look ugly". There isn't actually a newline in the string you're printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted your code into this SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static
void differentiate(char* polynomial) 
{
    char current[10];

    strncpy(current, strtok(polynomial, " []()/\n"), 10);
    printf("<<%s>>\n", current);

}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "Hello[]";
    printf("Before: <<%s>>\n", string);
    differentiate(string);
    printf("After:  <<%s>>\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
Before: <<Hello[]>>
<<Hello>>
After:  <<Hello>>
```

I was testing with GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, but I got the same result with the Apple-supplied GCC (`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`) and `clang` (`Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`).

You should justify your assertion that you got a newline out of `strtok()` by adapting this test and showing the output.  Note how the code uses the `<<` and `>>` to surround the string it is printing; if there's a newline in there, it will show up inside the double angle brackets.

Comment: You're right, the code isn't wrong, it's some weird behavior of the shell. Thanks for your help! Sorry for making such a big deal out of nothing.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that `fish` makes sure that even if the command's output doesn't end with a newline, the prompt is placed at the start of a new line.  Your code only used `printf("%s", strtok(...));`, without a newline at the end.  Classically, shells don't compensate for command output that does not end with a newline, and the prompt follows immediately after the output.  However, the C standard doesn't guarantee that output not ended with a newline will appear at all, AFAICR.

Comment: That seems to be right! I added a newline afterwards and it went away! Thanks so much for your help! I would vote you up if I could! Thanks again.